# Webstorm - How do I add Zurb Foundation as a new project type?

Tags: zurb-foundation, webstorm

I read in the documentation for WebStorm that when you create a New Project in Webstorm, you can select from a dropdown to use various project types including Twitter Bootstrap and Foundation.  But my dropdown doesn't have Foundation as an option.

How do I add Foundation as a drop-down project type in the New Project... dialog?

BTW, I'm using WebStorm v4.0.2

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

You should [update to a newer WebStorm version](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/index.html), this feature was added after 4.0.2 release.